# SSIS -- Allow a task to fail but have the package succeed?

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to allow a script task to fail, yet have the package execution result based only on the *other* tasks' execution results?  For example, I have 5 tasks.  I don't care what task 2's result is, but if any of the others fail, I want the package to fail.  Otherwise, I want it to succeed...

This possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting FailPackageOnFailure to False in the Task's Properties.

Next option will not actually fail your tasks, but may work for you:
Try wrapping your code into try catch and use finally to set Success for 2 tasks that you don't care about.

```
        try
        {
           // Do work here 
        }
        catch
        {
            // log errors here
        }
        finally
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for several reasons, the task has to fail sometimes.

Comment: This post have a link to a solution using EventHandlers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140850/the-best-way-for-a-ssis-ftp-task-to-not-fail-when-there-are-no-files-to-copy/306273#306273

Answer (score 5):

As well as setting `FailPackageOnFailure` on the task you should also set `MaximumErrorCount` on the package itself to something greater than 1.  The task will still increment the packages error count and if the error count exceeds `MaximumErrorCount` then the package can/will still fail.

Comment: Thanks, it was the MaximumErrorCount that was making it fail for me!

Comment: This was in my case. You saved my time.