# execute failure precedence constraint without showing task failure

Tags: sql-server, ssis, constraints, etl, operator-precedence

I have 3 tasks in an SSIS package. The first task is an `Execute Process Task` that runs a PowerShell command to download a file from a website. If the command fails the task fails. So I have two connections from it to two other tasks: one for success and one for failure.

The package works as expected. If the `Execute Process Task` succeeds it runs the associated success task. If the  fails it runs the associated failure task.

The problem is that if the `Execute Process Task` fails, it shows the task as failing even though it correctly/properly ran the failure task connected to it.

Is there anyway to get it to stop showing as failure but still run the associated failure task even when the `Execute Process Task` fails?

Comment: Yes there is a way - you google it! http://datachix.com/2011/02/08/messing-with-errors-in-ssis-or-does-the-propagate-property-really-exist/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i think the OP is asking to **remove the failure mark from the Execute Process Task**, and at the same time run the failure precedence constraint that is related to this task. It is a different case from `Foreach Loop container`. I don't think this can be done without a workaround

Comment: In the OP's comment below he adds "the package as a whole registers as a failure" - which is of course is not mentioned in the original post and makes a different question. The idea in the link should be able to be used for any task... though I'm not sure. I do recall doing this a different way (not marking the packages as failed) although I can't remember

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i think you're right, i updated my answer, just take a look

Answer (score 1):

## Update 1

If you need that the package doesn't result failure then you should set `FailPackageOnFailure` and `FailParentOnFailure` to `False` on the task you should also set `MaximumErrorCount` on the package itself to something greater than `1`. If the `Execute Process Task` fails it will increment the package's error count and if the error count exceeds `MaximumErrorCount` then the package can/will still fail. Else if you only need that the task doesn't shows failure it cannot be done

[SSIS -- Allow a task to fail but have the package succeed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648516/ssis-allow-a-task-to-fail-but-have-the-package-succeed) *(See all answers, not only the accepted one)*

---

## Initial Answer

**You cannot use a failure precedence constraint if the precedent task will always succeed**

I don't think you can do this. because the `failure` precedence constraint (connector) only works if the precedent task fail. You can use `ForceExecutionResult` property to let a task always success, but the failure connector will never be used.

## Workaround

I am not sure if this can help, but instead of using failure precedence constraint, store the Execution Value in a Variable, using `ExecValueVariable` property, and add Expressions to the precedence constraints *(both connector will have the `Success` constraint and a similar Expression:

```
@[User::ResultValue] = 1
```

OR

```
@[User::ResultValue] = 0
```

*Side Note: `ExecValueVariable` and `ForceExecutionResult` and other properties are found in the properties Tab, click on the Task and press F4 to show it*

Comment: The task does fail. If the PowerShell command being called by the `Execute Process Task` fails then the flow does go through the `failure` precedence connector. That all works. The issue is the `Execute Process Task` also shows as failure so the package as a whole registers as a failure. I would think that if a task failure is handled with a failure precedence constraint then the task would still succeed.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan if you need that the package doesn't result failure then you should set `FailPackageOnFailure` on the task you should also set `MaximumErrorCount` on the package itself to something greater than `1`. The task will still increment the packages error count and if the error count exceeds `MaximumErrorCount` then the package can/will still fail. Else if you only need that the task doesn't shows failure it cannot be done

Comment: `FailPackageOnFailure` and `FailParentOnFailure` are both set to `False` but no effect. And changing the `MaximumErrorCount` wont help since the task will fail no matter how many times it is run. I would think if a task has a failure connection then that's like saying "fail gracefully" so the task wouldn't show as a failure. Poor design if you ask me. Thanks though!

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan what you are aking for cannot be done, my answer update is only if executing the package from an SQL agent job or application and you want htat the package execution return success instead of failure

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan the only way you can do is **workarounds**

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you want the task to be shown as success even though the parent task fails and the task corresponding to the failure output is successful.
To do this you need to edit the field  FailTaskReturnCodeIsNotSuccessValue to False so that even though the parent task doesn't return the successValue the task is not shown as failed.Hope this helps!!.

Comment: I want the task to fail and route to the failure connection (which it does) but I don't want the task to show as failure because that fails the entire package.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan set `MaximumErrorCount` > the number of errors thrown by Execute Process Task

Comment: @Yahfoufi The `Execute Process Task` will either succeed or fail every time it is called. All it does is try to download a file using PowerShell. If the file is not there then it'll fail.