# Force execution result SSIS is not working

Tags: event-handling, ssis

I have a file system task in an SSIS control flow. If it fails, it should not fail the package.

I can force a success on the task itself, and disableEventHander, but how can I get the whole package to return 0 (value of success)?

Comment: Here`s the answer that worked:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053501/ssis-package-property-forceexecutionresult-does-not-work-as-expected?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the FailParentOnFailure property of the file system task to False.
2. Set the MaximumErrorCount of the file system task to a number that is high enough to accommodate the number of "normal" errors you may receive while running the task.

([See the Microsoft post from 9/3/10](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/381681/ssis100-failparentonfailure-failpackageonfailure-are-erroneously-regarded-to-be-always-true))

Answer (score 1):

Double click on the sequence line and change value to completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ForceExecutionValue` to `True` on the package itself and set the `ForceExecutionResult` to `Success` if you want to ALWAYS return a success, or alternatively you can set the `MaximumErrorCount` higher than the number of errors you have if you want to return success only when a certain number of failures happens.