# Indirection in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Is it possible to perform any sort of indirection in SSIS?

I have a series of jobs performing FTP and loops through the files before trying to run another DTSX package on them. Currently this incurs a lot of repeated cruft to pull down the file and logging.

Is there any way of redesigning this so I only need one package rather than 6?

Comment: Effectively the 6 packages are really 2 x 3. 1st for each "group" is FTP pull down and XML parsing to place into flat tables. Then 2nd then transforms and loads that data.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

```
Effectively the 6 packages are really 2 x 3. 1st for each "group" is FTP pull 
down  and XML parsing to place into flat tables. Then 2nd then transforms and 
loads that data.
```

Instead of downloading files using one package and inserting data into tables using another package, you can do that in a single package.

Here is a [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140850/the-best-way-for-a-ssis-ftp-task-to-not-fail-when-there-are-no-files-to-copy/6715972#6715972) containing an example which downloads files from FTP and saves it to local disk.

Here is a [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698075/ssis-2005-moving-file-after-parsing-in-foreach-loop-container/6703691#6703691) containing an example to loop through CSV files in a given folder and inserts that data into database.

Since you are using XML files, here is a [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152671/mapping-an-xml-file-to-a-database-with-ssis/6222777#6222777) that shows how to loop through XML files.

You can effectively combine the above examples into a single package by placing the control flow tasks one after the other.

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: The main issue is the fact I have to repeat the FTP and loop for each file type. I realise that it can all be done in one package but splitting the transform and load into a second simplified the complexity.